# How do I get my CheckBox to do something when it's checked?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox, checked

For example, I have 5 checkboxes (cb1 - cb5). cb1 is superior to others, which means it can only be checked if all the other 4 are checked. And if I check cb1, all the other 4 should automatically get checked. This is my current java code (this code is within onCreate method):

```
final CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
final CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
final CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
final CheckBox cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
final CheckBox cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( cb1.isChecked() )
        {
            cb2.isChecked();
            cb3.isChecked();
            cb4.isChecked();
            cb5.isChecked();
        }
    }
});
```

I'm a complete beginner so the code may be completely wrong or there's just a small error and I can't see it. Either way, I'd appreciate the help. Also, if my way is too complicated and there's an easier way, let me know please.

Comment: Use `setSelected(true)` if you want to check the checkbox. (`isChecked()` only checks if the checkbox is checked, it doesn't select/deselect it).

Comment: You should also setOnCheckedChangeListener for all your checkboxes, not just cb1. Also, you should consider just disabling cb1 until all the other checkboxes are checked. This will make it more obvious to the user what's going on.

Comment: @Maroun It looks like he is just using a Checkbox from java.awt, rather than from swing, so the command is setState(true) - but keep in mind that setting the state like that does not generate a check box selected event

Comment: @DavidChristo +1, 100%. Thanks, I missed that :) Post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the answer that I accepted helped me the most but every single answer and comment helped me to make it work, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for checkbox listener

```
public class CheckBoxListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    public CheckBoxListener() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox1: 
            //do something
        case R.id.checkBox2:

        case ...
        }

    }
}
```

Then set this listener to all your checkboxes:

```
final CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
final CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
final CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
final CheckBox cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
final CheckBox cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBoxListener());
cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBoxListener());
cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBoxListener());
cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBoxListener());
```

Comment: I didn't do it exactly like this in the end. I used IF loop and I didn't set listener to every button (just most of them) and it works perfectly! Thank you :)